# Is it possible to change AudioTrack title every 3 seconds

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am trying to change the AudioTrack title every 3 seconds, but It seems I cannot change it or it could not be possible using below:

```
void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  BackgroundAudioPlayer player = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance;
  switch (player.PlayerState)
  {
    case PlayState.Playing:
    if (recitation != null && recitation.Count > 0)
    {
        if (++ayaRecitationCounter == recitation.Count)
        {
           ayaRecitationCounter = 0;
           recitationTimer.Stop();
        }
        else
        {
           player.Track.Title = ayaRecitationCounter.ToString(); //Exception occurs here   recitationTimer.Interval=TimeSpan.FromSeconds(recitation[ayaRecitationCounter].AyaDuration);
           lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex = ayaRecitationCounter;
           lsbReadingChapter.ScrollIntoView(lsbReadingChapter.SelectedIndex);
         }
       }
       break;
       }
}
```

The application is crushing and providing me below message:

```
Operation is not valid due to the current state of the object.
   at Microsoft.Phone.BackgroundAudio.AudioTrack.set_Title(String value)
```

How can I change the title?

Thanks!

Comment: Weere does that Timer exist? Main UI?

Comment: Yeah, but I start that when playing starts. Initializing occurs in constructor.

Comment: In constructor of BackgroundAudioPlayer?

Comment: In constructor of my MainPage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to Edit AudioTrack once it's created you will have to use BeginEdit as [MSDN says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.backgroundaudio.audiotrack%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

> Once the track has been created using one of the AudioTrack constructors, then the BeginEdit() and EndEdit() methods must be used to update the object.

As I've checked - I was able to change Title (for example) while playing by this code:

```
AudioTrack track = BackgroundAudioPlayer.Instance.Track;
track.BeginEdit();
track.Title = "New Title";
track.EndEdit();
```

(accessing by a reference is needed here)

Of course it will be suitable to put some try-catch blocks in your code.
Pease also be aware that your `Timer` will work only when your App is in Foreground.

Comment: Thanks. I am changing this from foreground as I have timer.

Comment: @ARH Then give me only a sign if that worked with Timer.

Comment: Just a question: I am changing the title from foreground, when I lock the device the title doesn't get changed. Is it possible to track the position of audio in background, when It reaches that position i should be able to change title in the background.

Comment: @ARH With `locking` you can manage to do that with disablong ApplicationIdleDetection. But when your App is in background (you hit start button) it gets harder. You can use Background Agent (not player) but they don't work in 3 seconds interval. I don't know if faking BAP would run and even so if it will pass certification.